# Declining endings - what am I missing?

Tags: dative

There is a simple German sentence on Busuu that I cannot understand. "Wir gehen in eine Bar in einer kleinen Straße." = "We are going to a bar on a little street." But why kleinen, with "EN"? Surely, if dative it would be "einer kleinER Straße"? Would you please also say if it is Dative/Accusative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in dative case. In German, adjectives are inflected differently depending on whether they occur (1) after a definite article (*der*, also *derselbe, dieser*, and some others), (2) after an indefinite article like *ein, kein, mein*, or after (3) a null article.

- definite article (weak inflection): *eine Bar in der kleine**n** Straße*
- indefinite article (mixed inflection): *eine Bar in einer kleine**n** Straße*
- null article (strong inflection): [The painting is titled:] *Bar in kleine**r** Straße*

You can find the declension table of *klein* on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/klein#Declension), among other places. You're looking for the correct ending when the adjective is accompanied by an indefinite article ("mixed inflection"), which in this (dative) case is *-en*: *einer kleinen*.

Since there probably is little point in me writing the 10,000th introduction to German adjective inflection ;-), I will rest here and just recommend the Wikipedia article on [German adjectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_adjectives) or essentially any introductory grammar of the German language.

Comment: Nancy Thuleen's flowchart isn't quite correct in that it produces the wrong endings for masculine and neuter genitive. Admittedly this doesn't come up very often.

Comment: @RDBury It does? Do you have an example?

Comment: Please, when ever you post pictures that contain text, then please also write the text in your posting. Nobody will be able to read what's written in the image if imgur.com is down. Also blind people have seriously troubles reading anything that is not available as normal text. Blind people use tools that will read texts, but these tools can't read pictures. (This is why I gave -1) Also please do not post here-links. If "here" is a useful explanation, then please write this explanation in your posting. If it contains just additional information, then please name the site.

Comment: @johnl: Masculine and neuter genitive with no article - The flowchart says use the der-word ending, but the der-word is *des* and adjectives end with *-en*. In general her site has useful teaching materials, but there are occasional small errors like this.

Comment: I have removed the flowchart based on Hubert Schölnast's comment, so this is obsolete now. Thanks anyhow for the clarification, @RDBury - this does indeed appear to be an inaccuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Though the details can be confusing and hard to master, the basic principle is that only one word in the phrase needs to be fully inflected. If the article is *einer* then that already has a fully inflected ending and you don't need another one for the adjective. This doesn't mean the adjective is not inflected at all; it gets a weak, or as I prefer to call it, partial inflection. So *einer kleinen Straße*. The article *ein* has no inflection ending, so you do need to fully inflect the adjective. So *ein schönes Mädchen*. You still need to learn the full and partial inflection patterns but that's not as hard as it might seem.

The same principle applies in other situations as well, for example *beide* is normally inflected according to case: N, A *beide*; D *beiden*; G *beider*. But if there's an article or other determiner in front of it then that takes the "inflection load" off *beide* and it's only partially inflected. Since *beide* is only used with plurals, and partial inflections for plurals always end *-en*, you'd only use *beiden* in that case. So *Beide Jungen spielen Gitarre,* but *Meine beiden Söhne spielen Gitarre.*

Comment: Good clear examples.